# How to build a concealing box around a gas utility meter

Tags: gas

I would like to build a concealing box around my gas utility meter, for aesthetic purposes.

My understanding is that it must be well vented, for obvious reasons. Furthermore, the dials and serial number must be exposed.

Does "vented" mean slats on three sides? Must the bottom or top be open (to avoid accumulation)?

Can anyone point me to some suitable designs (pictures)?

There are plenty of examples for electricity ultility meters, but I lack ideas for gas meters.

I am also concerned about vermin making a home there. Would you cover the openings with mesh?

And, is it preferable to have it floating and attached to the siding/sheating, or on feet? The meter in question is under eaves and above a small concrete pad.

The utility company needs access for visual reading and any repairs, so it should be easy to remove. It (obviously) cannot hang off the meter itself, its struts or pipes, and so it will need its own independent support.

Comment: First talk to your gas co.  They have if a box/covering can be used.  One idea is top closed, two sides with open slats, open bottom and a front door with window(plastic).

Comment: @crip659 I edited my Q to include the company's few requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me, I would make a simple 5-sided box, leaving the bottom open for easy installation. I would set it on some sort of metal or plastic foot to keep the wood off the ground to reduce its rate of rot. If there's a concrete pad around the meter, simply drilling holes for short 1/4" lag bolts and using the bolt heads as your feet would do the trick.

I would cut a hole in the "face" to allow it to be easily read (though most are read remotely these days) in person. I would also cut several vents in the top. Obviously, it would need a slit in one (or more) side(s) so it can slide over any pipes that don't go directly down into the ground. I would think that would probably be enough to prevent any significant heat build up within the box and, should there ever be a gas leak, it would also let the gas out. I would also cover all the holes with some screen door mesh to keep little critters out while still allowing air flow and the ability to see the face of the meter for reading.

Most importantly, I would call the gas company for an inspection before installing it. Simply tell them you're building a decorative, ventilated cover for the meter and that you'd like to have it inspected by them to ensure it meets any and all requirements they may have before you install<sup>*</sup> it. They may tell you right away that *no* cover is acceptable, or they may schedule to have a representative come take a look. If you ask nicely, I'm sure you'll get a nice response.

---

<sup>*</sup>"Install" meaning "to place over the meter and set on the ground". I don't intend to imply any sort of permanent installation, or even any sort of attachment that would require anything more than a simple two-handed lift to remove.

Comment: Install? I would say hang on some hooks or something along those lines. I would think the gas company would want to be able to remove it without the use of tools.

Comment: Yes. Let me add: they need access for reading and any repairs, so making it easy to remove is a good point. It (obviously) cannot hang off the meter struts or pipes, and needs its own independent support.

Comment: Good communication is _so_ difficult. By "install", I meant "carefully place the box on the ground, fitting it over the meter without banging into anything". I didn't mean to imply any sort of screw-it-down/embed-it-in-concrete type of "installation". Simply a box that can be placed over the meter, then picked up and removed whenever necessary.

Comment: Hope that's better, @PlatinumGoose.

Comment: @FreeMan I think that's indeed important point you highlighted and I had not considered. Electrical utility cover boxes are usually installed against the house, they have a door or removable front, and are permanently integrated with the siding. With gas it should be a completely removable box providing work space and access to the meter from all sides.

Comment: The pipe slots can go back to the wall or down to the base.

Comment: Good point, @Jasen. To me, "drop the box over the meter" is more intuitive than "slide the box toward the house", but either way works, and the OP is more than welcome to do what works best for him.

Comment: @freeman good answer, I just commented because you never know what some posters will do.